# View disappear after animating out of Screen bounds

Tags: android, animation, view, screen, bounds

I'm implementing an `Animation` for one menu in my project.

The animation itself is ok, the menu enters and exit just as I wanted: Slide from left to right and right to left, however...

If the entire view is OUT of the screen, then it NEVER comes back egain! If, at least one pixel is still inside the screen, then it comes back normally.

I belive that Android is disposing the layout, and not caring about it after out of the screen bounds. I tried to place a `setVisibility(VISIBLE)` but it also didn't worked.

Here is the code:

```
public class ChwaziMenuAnimation extends Animation{

        float posStart = 0;
        float posTarget = 100;

        int getCurrentPosition(){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rootParam =
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.getLayoutParams();

            return rootParam.leftMargin;
        }

        public void setTarget(float target){
            // Save current position
            posStart = getCurrentPosition();
            posTarget = target;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rootParam =
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.getLayoutParams();

            // Calculate current position
            rootParam.leftMargin = (int) ((posTarget - posStart) * interpolatedTime + posStart);

            rootView.setLayoutParams(rootParam);
        }

        /*
         *  Since we will be animating the margin, the bounds will always change 
         */
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        };


    };
```

And how I initialize the animation:

```
public void appear(){

        Log.i(TAG, "appear");

        menuAnimation.setTarget(0);
        menuAnimation.setDuration(750);
        rootView.clearAnimation();
        rootView.startAnimation(menuAnimation);
    }

    public void disapear(){
        Log.i(TAG, "disapear");

        menuAnimation.setTarget(-400);
        menuAnimation.setDuration(750);
        rootView.startAnimation(menuAnimation);
    }
```

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but just wanted to let you know that this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39223310/4479004

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, my workaround so far is to extend the view bounds to at least one pixel on the displayable area, and make that part transparent. Ugly, but for me it seems to work.

To make it even more weird: the view did not disappear, when shifted out the right side of the screen, only when shifted out the left side of the screen. But that might be device dependent.

Comment: The same happend to me.. only disappeared when shifting to the left of the screen.